# Exclude Strings in Previews from Localization Export

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, localization

I have a bunch of strings in my several SwiftUI previews, but the problem is that they get included in Xcodes *Export Localizations* feature. **Is there a way to automatically prevent that strings from `PreviewProvider`’s get exported for localization?**

I’ve already tried to wrap the `PreviewProvider` structs in `#if DEBUG`, but that that didn’t work.

### My Current Workaround

1. Use `Text(verbatim: "")`
2. Wrap other strings in `String("")`

Though, that’s really annoying to wrap all of the previews strings this way. I can’t be the only one that wants to exclude the preview strings, right?

Comment: You can't exclude them, but what's the problem if export contains strings from previews? after all one day you may need to preview a particular locale, and here it will be ready, as opposed to scrambling "how this string looks in Mandarin" or something... If you want to identify which strings in exported localization are from preview, then just use a `comment` argument: `Text("key", comment: "Preview for ... ")`, which will appear as comment above key in localization file.

Comment: @klangfarb Well, I don’t need and want my Hello World, Lorem Ipsum or „this is a very long button title“ phrases in the localizable strings. Previews are for testing and most of the time I test things with dummy or random data to see how my components behave in certain conditions. No need to pollute the localizable strings with that nonsense. ;)

Comment: Well, something doesn't add up for me here. Why your previews have UI elements that are not in prod code to begin with? Let say you have preview for List row. So you may need a data model that is fake / sample. But why do you need a special `Text` for preview? Maybe think in that direction

Comment: @klangfarb I do indeed use a example data model for bigger/complex views. Though mostly for custom components (like button, label, etc.) I’m just using simple `Text` or `Strings` in my previews. It’s way simpler to just throw this in there instead of linking it to my example model, preparing a thing that it only displays one label of something and so on. Not sure why this would be unusual. ‍♂️

Comment: It's unusual because by defining Text in PreviewProvider you are no longer "previewing" existing view, you are creating a new one that will only exist as preview. I.e. a difference between `struct X_Previews: PreviewProvider { MyExistingView(some state / variables) }` vs `struct X_Previews: PreviewProvider { you are building some new view here with Text etc }`. Anyways, it's up to you. But you cannot disable the localization at the moment.

Answer (score -3):

xCode 15.0.1

#Preview - it will help you.

example:

```
#Preview {
   return  VStack {
        Button("Continue") {}.buttonStyle(MButtonStyle())
        Button("Continue TB") {}.buttonStyle(TButtonStyle())
        Button(action: { print("Button tapped")},
               label: { Text("Custom Button").frame(maxWidth: .infinity) })
        .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        .cornerRadius(30)
        .tint(Color("mRed"))

        Button("Custom Button") {
            print("Button tapped")
        }
        .overlay( RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30.0).stroke(lineWidth: 2.0))
        .buttonStyle(FullWidthButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

"Continue", "Continue TB", etc will not appear in Localizable string catalog

Comment: Hmm, that doesn’t work for me. Even when using the `#Preview` macro, the strings appear in my localizable string catalog …

Comment: Build project and then it disappear.

Comment: I’ve tested it with two projects, one only using `#Preview` and one using a mix of old and new. In both cases the strings appear in my string catalog. Building the project does in fact add them back, after removing `verbatim:` …

Comment: I'm pretty certain that Xcode 15.0 ignored strings that were only defined in SwiftUI previews, but in Xcode 15.2 these strings are also added to the string catalog.